# Creating a 2D list from a column using values from 2 other columns in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns which represent the X & Y dimension of a 2D array that needs to be created. The value in the 2D array will come from another column in the dataframe. In case there is more than 1 value column in the dataframe, then same number of 2D lists needs to be created.

So far I've been able to create 1 2D list assuming there is only 1 value column in the dataframe. I created an empty 2D list of the same dimension based on the X & Y columns in the dataframe. Then I loop through each row of the dataframe and fill the 2D list based on the value of X & Y in that row.

Example dataframe. X represent the 'columns' of the 2D list, and Y represents the 'rows' of the 2D list. In this case the 2D list is 3x2. The column (numeric_result, voltage) will fill up the 2D list.

```
      | parent | child | numeric_result | X | Y |
index |                |        voltage |
    0 |     xy |     a |            1.2 | 1 | 1 | 
    1 |     xy |     a |            1.1 | 2 | 1 |
    2 |     xy |     a |            1.2 | 3 | 1 | 
    3 |     xy |     a |            1.1 | 1 | 2 |
    4 |     xy |     a |            1.0 | 2 | 2 |
    5 |     xy |     a |            1.3 | 3 | 2 |
```

First I create the 2D list:

```
rows = 2
cols = 3    

def make2dList(rows, cols):    
    a=[]    
    for row in range(rows): a += [[0]*cols]    
    return a
list2d = make2dList(rows, cols)
```

Then I populate the list.

```
def fill2dlist(a, dataframe):
    # Loop through each row of dataframe 
    for i in range(len(dataframe.index)):
        col = int(dataframe.iloc[i].X)
        row = int(dataframe.iloc[i].Y)
        a[row-1][col-1] = (pd.to_numeric(dataframe.loc[i,'numeric_result'].values[0]))
    return a

finallist = modify2dlist(list2d, dataframe)
print(finallist)

[[1.2, 1.1, 1.2],[1.1, 1.0, 1.3]]
```

This seems inefficient. Is there a way to vectorize this or somehow make it faster?

In addition, I want to make a new dataframe like below where there are many combination of parent & child. Any help would be appreciated on how to create this dataframe. Thanks!

```
      | parent | child |                numeric_result_list |
index |                |                            voltage |
    0 |     xy |     a | [[1.2, 1.1, 1.2], [1.1, 1.0, 1.3]] | 
    1 |     xy |     b | [[1.1, 1.0, 1.1], [1.4, 1.3, 1.5]] |       
    2 |     xy |     c | [[1.1, 1.0, 1.6], [1.4, 1.8, 1.5]] |               
    3 |     yz |     e | [[1.4, 1.2, 1.2], [1.7, 1.2, 1.0]] |
```

Edit here is my code to create the dataframe with the 2D list. Any help would be appreciated to make it efficient.

```
# Create an empty dataframe with column names
dffinal = pd.DataFrame(columns=['parent','child','numeric_result_list'])

# Group by 'parent' and 'child'
parent_child = df2.groupby(['parent', 'child'])

i = 1
for name, group in parent_child:

    print('Processing: ', name)
    group = group.reset_index(drop=True)

    _array2d_ = make2dList(rows, cols)
    _array2d_ = modify2dlist(_array2d_, _group_)

    dffinal.loc[i] = [name[0], name[1], _array2d_]
    i = i+1
    print('done')

dff = dff.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the 2D list generation process by using multi-indexing.

```
yarray = np.arange(min(df.Y),max(df.Y)+1,1)
xarray = np.arange(min(df.X),max(df.X)+1,1)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([yarray, xarray], names=['Y', 'X'])
```

idx gives all cartesian combinations of Y & X. Then I use the idx to index the dataframe. Below code also fills NaNs in columns like parent & child which I am trying to figure out how to avoid.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688938/pandas-insert-rows-where-data-is-missing$    
df1 = df.set_index(['Y', 'X']).reindex(idx) 

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134012/pandas-dataframe-fillna-only-some-columns-in-place$    
df1['numeric_result'] = df1['numeric_result'].fillna(value=0)
```

Before using numpy reshape, I sort the dataframe using the Y & X indices.

```
df1= df1.sort_values(by=['Y','X'])
array = np.reshape(df1.numeric_result.values, (len(yarray,len(xarray)))
```